# Does law of inertia has anything to do with speed of light?

Tags: forces, visible-light, speed-of-light, inertia

I am not physics student so please pardon me if this sounds silly because I might be mixing irrelevant things here and I am not even getting how to ask my question.

My main question is, does light travels at the same speed irrespective of from where/who/how the light is created/generated (assuming light travelling in vacuum)? Meaning, the light coming from a candle or a beam from a lazer gun or a sun rays or light coming from any other star takes same time to travel from Point A to Point B? Does energy and force what caused that light to be generated has any impact on how fast they move?

When I think of moving of photons my basic physics knowledge which I learnt in childhood tells me that for moving anything some force has to be applied and speed and distance of the object depends on how much force is applied. I am hoping its same for the photons too. In that case what I wonder is the light from a match stick, lighter, torch, lazer, sun or any bigger and larger star is same? They will be same unless all applies same force to the photon.

Comment: Are you asking does it take energy to emit a photon, and the more energy, the further the electron travels?

Comment: Not exactly. But I have question related to it which I partly asked jn the question. But to avoid confusion. My question is related to how photon is moved. I assumed there could be some force applied to it if think of law of inerria which states anything for moving some force is applied.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does law of inertia has anything to do with speed of light?

Yes. Inertia is *resistance to change in motion*. It doesn't take much effort to get a skateboard moving, or to stop it moving. But it takes a lot of effort to get a locomotive moving, or to stop it moving. That's because the locomotive is more massive. And as [Einstein said](https://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/E_mc2/www/), the mass of a body is a measure of its energy content. The relationship between mass and energy is given by E=mc² where c is the speed of light. Hence inertia has something to do with the speed of light. Maybe not much, but you did say *anything to do with*.

**Edited:**

> My main question is, does light travels at the same speed irrespective of from where/who/how the light is created/generated (assuming light travelling in vacuum)?

Yes, in that light doesn't overtake light. Because of the particular wave nature of light. The wave speed doesn't vary like it does for [waves in the ocean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_wave#Physics_of_waves). But note things like the [Shapiro Delay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro_delay) article on Wikipedia where you can read that *"the speed of a light wave depends on the strength of the gravitational potential along its path"*.

> Meaning, the light coming from a candle or a beam from a laser gun or a sun rays or light coming from any other star takes same time to travel from Point A to Point B?

Yes. All the light travels at the same speed between A and B in vacuum. This isn't quite true in say glass or water, hence prisms and rainbows. But there are no rainbows associated with gravitational lensing.

> Does energy and force what caused that light to be generated has any impact on how fast they move?

No. The speed depends on the properties of space, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light#Propagation_of_light) where you can read that *the speed c with which electromagnetic waves (such as light) propagate through the vacuum is related to the electric constant ε<sub>0</sub> and the magnetic constant μ<sub>0</sub> by the equation $c={\frac {1}{\sqrt {\varepsilon _{0}\mu _{0}}}}$.*

> When I think of moving of photons my basic physics knowledge which I learnt in childhood tells me that for moving anything some force has to be applied and speed and distance of the object depends on how much force is applied. I am hoping its same for the photons too.

It isn't. You can't push a photon to make it go faster or slower. That's because the photon has an [E=hf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon#Physical_properties) wave nature. It isn't a body like a locomotive is a body. However it does offer *resistance to change of motion*, and you can accelerate a photon in the vector sense via Compton scattering:

[image]<sub>Image courtesy of Rod Nave's [hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/compton.html#c1)</sub>

That's because it has a non-zero "inertial mass". Which is why Einstein said *"if the theory corresponds to the facts, radiation conveys inertia between the emitting and absorbing bodies"*. Note though that inertial mass is better thought of as a measure of energy. The the meaning of the word mass has changed over the decades such that it's nowadays assumed to mean rest mass. A radiating body loses mass, and the absorbing body gains it. But the photon isn't at rest and you can't slow it down, so rest mass doesn't apply.

> In that case what I wonder is the light from a match stick, lighter, torch, laser, sun or any bigger and larger star is same? They will be same unless all applies same force to the photon.

The light consists of photons of difference frequencies, and there may be differences in the polarization, but other than that I can't think of any other differences.

Answer (score 4):

The rest mass of photons is zero. Hence, they do not have any inertia. Asking how do you accelerate a photon is a meaningless question (however, note that changing direction is allowed and you can accelerate photons that way but even saying so is also technically wrong because light isn't really accelerating, it moves along the curvature of spacetime).

The photons must travel at the speed of light. It is a fact. Any particle which has zero rest mass must travel at the speed of light. If it does not, it is not of any interest to us because it will have zero momentum and zero energy and hence, it will be undetectable. If you want to know why, ask a new question.

Comment: If light is made photons then what you said "photons must travel at the speed of the light" is confusing me.

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question. (Check for duplicates before you do that)

Comment: If you are interested, trying messing around with these formulas. Assume that a massless particle does not travel at the speed of light and see what you get. $E^2 = (mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2$ and $p = m_o v\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$

Answer (score 1):

Photon have momentum not inertia as their rest mass is zero

And their momentum is due to thier kinetic energy

Actually lighting the matchstick we transfer chemical energy to excite electron of atom and when the electron de-excites to lower stable energy level it do so by emitting photon

In bulb electrical energy converted to heat energy which excites electron

Answer (score -1):

When a photon move, there is just interaction of **Electric field** & **Magnetic field** and not matter-matter interaction. Instead of inertia there is absorption of energy in the matter-photon interaction, so all the energy of photon help in movement of atom, which ultimately provide Kinetic energy to a particle.